# Install two Wordpress website on one VM with Static IP Address

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I want to run two WordPress website on one IP address. I have a windows server 2016 and I want to run an Ubuntu VM that has a static IP address that contains two WordPress CMS.each of this WordPress Websites should map to a subdomain or subfolder in my main domain. like this:

192.168.1.100/CMS1 ==> maidomain.com/CMS1

192.168.1.100/CMS2 ==> maidomain.com/CMS2

what is the best solution for this propose?
is there any tutorial or document for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the below lines in your `host` file.

```
192.168.1.100 maidomain.com www.maidomain.com
```

Now you can install unlimited sub sites with domain  maidomain.com .

> For Eg:  maidomain.com/cms1, maidomain.com/cms2, maidomain.com/cms3 etc.